# windows system image on new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

Let's say I have a Windows system image backup. And my computer fails. Can I take that backup image and restore on a new computer? One that will most likely have varied hardware, but maybe the same OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by system image backup you mean a bootable image, you can prepare it for deployment on to a new PC by running sysprep BEFORE you make the image.

Run c:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe, select Enter System Out-Of-Box experience (oobe) and under shutdownoptions select shutdown rather than reboot. Once the machine is shut down you can take an image of harddrive or move it to boot a new desktop.

Prior to running sysprep, you can customise the windows installation to your needs.

Comment: This might be the link I'm looking for: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preparing-an-image-using-sysprep-and-imagex.aspx